# Having trouble reading and understanding the following SQL Code for Pacing, remodifying

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have some SQL code that I am trying to remodify for a tableau dashboard.

The original SQL looks is this,

"
[Total Gross Revenue]/([Total Gross Revenue Goal] * DATEDIFF(‘day’, DATETRUNC(‘month’, MAX([pstday])), MAX([pstday]) + 1) / MIN(DATEDIFF(‘day’, DATETRUNC(‘month’, [pstday]), DATETRUNC(‘month’, DATEADD(‘month’, 1, [pstday])))))

"

So what it does is that as the days/weeks pass by, it allows for the dashboard to do something like

"At the current rate, on track to complete SQLscriptnumber% of the original target of #targetnumbermn"

Now I am trying to modify this so it fits in terms of weeks of the month. So in the previous example, the script filtered on months, based on a pstday column.

However I no longer have that pstday column, and only have pstmonth column and a pstweek column.

However Id like to go as pstmonth column as pstweek could have a different month ahead since thats how it was accounted for in the targets.

So far I tried playing around with it, what I got to work was this,

"
SUM([Ad Revenue])/(SUM([Total Gross Revenue Goal]) * DATEDIFF(‘day’, DATETRUNC(‘month’, MAX([pstmonth])), MAX([pstmonth]) + 1) / MIN(DATEDIFF(‘day’, DATETRUNC(‘month’, [pstmonth]), DATETRUNC(‘month’, DATEADD(‘month’, 1, [pstmonth])))))

"

But the number that shows up is incorrect. How would I modify this to achieve what I am trying to do? I am also confused on the original code and why it does " + 1" at the DATETRUNC function.

Comment: The datepart in DATEDIFF should not be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer.  The +1 is required to get the correct day of the month.  All that part of the code is doing is getting the day of the month.  On the first day of the month, 1 - 1 is zero.  Adding 1 gives the day of the month.  You can test it using the code below to see that DATEPART will simplify the expression.

The dominator is the number of days in the month. It can be simplified as shown below.

I'm not using SQL2022 and did not have DATETRUNC, but it was easy enough to replace.

```
WITH N16 as ( -- 16 records
    SELECT t.N
    FROM (
        VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)
        ) t (N)
), N4096 as ( -- 16 * 16 * 16 records with values from 1 to 16 * 16 * 16
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n1.N) as N
    FROM N16 n1
    CROSS JOIN N16 n2
    CROSS JOIN N16 n3
), SampleDates as ( -- a bunch of dates
    SELECT N + GETDATE() as SampleDate -- adding a integer adds days to a datetime - invalid for a datetime2
    FROM N4096
) select SampleDate, 
    dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, SampleDate), 0) as [FirstDayOfMonth], -- non-SQL2022 version of DATETRUNC for month
    DATEDIFF(day, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, SampleDate), 0), SampleDate + 1) as [WhatIsThis], 
    DATEPART(day, SampleDate) as [DayOfMonth],
    DATEPART(day, EOMONTH(SampleDate)) as [DaysInMonth]
from SampleDates
--where DATEDIFF(day, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, SampleDate), 0), SampleDate + 1) <> DATEPART(day, SampleDate)
```

```
SampleDate              FirstDayOfMonth         WhatIsThis  DayOfMonth  DaysInMonth
----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2022-08-30 20:30:03.657 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 30          30          31
2022-08-31 20:30:03.657 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 31          31          31
2022-09-01 20:30:03.657 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 1           1           30
2022-09-02 20:30:03.657 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 2           2           30
2022-09-03 20:30:03.657 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 3           3           30
2022-09-04 20:30:03.657 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 4           4           30
...
2022-09-27 20:30:03.657 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 27          27          30
2022-09-28 20:30:03.657 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 28          28          30
2022-09-29 20:30:03.657 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 29          29          30
2022-09-30 20:30:03.657 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 30          30          30
2022-10-01 20:30:03.657 2022-10-01 00:00:00.000 1           1           31
2022-10-02 20:30:03.657 2022-10-01 00:00:00.000 2           2           31
```

If given another time interval like weeks of the month, then perhaps report on the last date of each week of the month?  Report at the end of each work week?  If you have a list of dates of the month for the report, then the same formula seems like it would be fine.  It would be a subset of a daily report.